# C++ PPL - initialize a combinable

Tags: c++, parallel-processing, ppl

Let's say that in enclosing scope, I have some variables that each thread in a parallel_for loop should access. I have an idea combinable would suits, making one copy of my variable in each thread. However, I don't understand how to initialize my combinable thing:

For instance I want to use copies of a QString formula. I create a combinable standing for the copied things in each thread:

```
 combinable<QString> formulaRx;
```

Should I write then :

```
parallel_for(0,p,[&formulaRx, formula](int i)
{
         formulaRx.local() = formula;

         // do things

 });
```

? Would this solve the problem, or would there still be concurrent access with the line

```
 formulaRx.local() = formula;
```

What is the proper way to handle this?

Please tell me if not clear

Thanks and regardS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you do not need to assign `formulaRx.local()`.
 This is a getter for the local copy of the combinable object.

```
parallel_for(0,p,(int i)
{
     QString f = formulaRx.local();

     // do things with f which is the local copy of formulaRx

});
```

Comment: Thanks. However, I should have been more precise: I am also working with pointers in the same situation:: what if formula is a pointer? Then I guess 'pointers' f would point to same thing.